# Blank page after deployment on Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

The application is Web Api .Net 6.0. When I run locally everything seems to be ok, however when I deploy the application on Azure I get blank page. I check the logs and I'm getting the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>IIS Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found</title><style type="text/css"><!--body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px;font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}a:hover{text-decoration:none;}h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;}#details-right th{width:20%;}table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}.clear{clear:both;}.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}--></style>
</head><body><div id="content"><div class="content-container"><h3>HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found</h3><h4>The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h4></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4><ul>  <li>The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.</li>  <li>The URL contains a typographical error.</li>    <li>A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.</li> </ul></fieldset></div><div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4><ul>  <li>Create the content on the Web server.</li>  <li>Review the browser URL.</li>    <li>Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439">here</a>. </li> </ul></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4><div id="details-left"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModuleV2</td></tr><tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr><tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x00000000</td></tr>
</table></div><div id="details-right"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://ODWEApi20230711094215:80/</td></tr><tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\home\site\wwwroot</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr><tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
</table><div class="clear"></div></div></fieldset></div>
<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=404,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p><p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>
</fieldset></div></div></body></html>
```

or Image:
[image: screenshot]

I'm confused since in VisualStudio I can see on publish the application is uploaded. On azure there are 60.41MB.
This is can not be related with the current application, since I test it with blank Web Api application(WeatherForecast) and publish it to Azure. It's having the same problem - blank page
What could be he issue?

Comment: 404 means content is not there. How have you deployed the app? can you see the uploaded files on Azure?

Comment: @DivyangDesai I uploaded the files. On azure - Usage (this ASP)60.41MiB. In VS - ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: It seems all apis are working but I can't see swagger page

Comment: I changed  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) to  if (app.Environment.IsProduction())  and its ok